# AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__val1'

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes

So I'm trying to make a basic Class function program, and I got stuck at an early phase on something weird. I have functions opening text files to create the Class objects and all, but the problem is that I can't seem to be able to call any object values. Here's the gist of how my objects are generated:

```
Class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,val1,val2):
         self.__val1 = val1
         self.__val2 = val2

def main():
    dict = {}
    ...
    dict[key] = MyClass(val1, val2)
```

And at this point I should be able to call the object values with

```
    dict[key].__val1
    dict[key].__val2
```

but keep getting the error in the title.

Comment: variables with `__` starting are name mangled with class name to behave as a private variable. They should not be used outside the class definition. if you still want to use it prepend it with `_className` to access it

Comment: To be honest I was using "__" only because of imitating earlier codes, not because I knew what their intent was

Comment: this might be helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double underscore names are mangled by adding "`_ClassName`" before their name. *Inside* class methods, you can reference these names with `__var1` notation and Python takes care to actually find them for you.

Outside the class body you'll need to provide the *full mangled name* in order to access it, that is:

```
print(d[k]._MyClass__val1)
```

As an aside, even though this might be an example, don't use names like `dict`; they mask their built-in counterparts. Use a name like `d` as I have here.